# I need to copy a row of data and append it to the bottom of another list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my script

```
function testmoveContact() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form")
var destination = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

sheet.getRange("A2:G2").copyTo(destination.appendRow, {contentsOnly: true});


}
```

This script works if I use getRange instead of appendRow, however I need the data to copy to the bottom of a set of data.

It give me the error "Exception: The parameters (String,(class)) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.copyTo." I don't understand this error.

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample sheet where we can replicate your script?

Answer (score 1):

With appendrow you're supposed to give the values of the cells inside that call, and not to name a range. You can try it like this:

```
var lastRow = destination.getLastRow()

sheet.getRange("A2:G2").copyTo(destination.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,7),{contentsOnly: true})
```